# Is this how I would calculate the FOV when I have distortion?

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, geometry

Following this [resource](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/parameters.html), I believe I understand how the Plumb Bob model for distortion works.

What I couldn't find, was how to apply this to the calculation of field of view (FOV). To get you used to my notation, without distortion it's

```py
def calculate_fov(
        K: np.ndarray, resolution: Tuple[int, int]) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """
    Calculate fov given intrisic matrix and image size
    Args:
        K - (3, 3) intrinsics matrix
        resolution - (width, height)
    """
    fx = K[0, 0]
    fy = K[1, 1]
    return (2 * np.arctan(resolution[0] * 0.5 / fx), 2 * np.arctan(resolution[1] * 0.5 / fy))
```

Now some back of the envelope math makes me think I can get away with getting some sort of "modified" or "effective" focal lengths.

[image]

So to "adjust" `fx` we just multiply it by the radial distortion coefficient.

So my modified function is

```py
def calculate_fov(
        K: np.ndarray, resolution: Tuple[int, int], D: Optional[np.ndarray] = None) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """
    Calculate fov given intrisic matrix and image size
    Args:
        K - (3, 3) intrinsics matrix
        resolution - (width, height)
        D - Optional (5,) with distortion model
    """
    fx = K[0, 0]
    fy = K[1, 1]
    # Adjust fx and fy based on distortion http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/parameters.html
    if D is not None:
        rx = resolution[0] * 0.5 / fx
        fx = fx * (1 + D[0] * rx**2 + D[1] * rx**4 + D[4] * rx**6)
        ry = resolution[1] * 0.5 / fy
        fy = fy * (1 + D[0] * ry**2 + D[1] * ry**4 + D[4] * ry**6)
    return (2 * np.arctan(resolution[0] * 0.5 / fx), 2 * np.arctan(resolution[1] * 0.5 / fy))
```

In words, the idea is to take the widest possible point in my image, work out how much that point would be moved because of distortion, then use that in the basic trigonometry for FOV. I just can't find any resources to confirm this, and I'm a little suspicious of the order of operations/logic. And I'm not sure it was fair of me to disregard the tangential distortion.

Comment: perhaps check your work with an actual camera that has some distortion. most "action cameras" have very nice distortion.

Comment: Would love to, just don't have a camera. I've expanded out the T to check and indeed I think my working checks out. But it doesn't make sense off-axis. In fact, it doesn't really make sense to define an exact FOV for that reason.

Comment: diagonal FoV considering corner-to-corner angle, sure. just not terribly useful because those corners don't leave much field. horizontal/vertical FoV should be more interesting.